# Need to create a big shutdown button

Tags: shutdown

While I wrote some of the login security for Unix System V and have been using Ubuntu on an old laptop for email and surfing for a few years, my Unix skills have atrophied and knowledge of Ubuntu is limited.

I want to move my 90+ year old mother to Ubuntu due to her limited computer use (email, skype, surfing, facebook) and would like to have a very obvious shutdown button. I'll be installing the latest Ubuntu release using all the defaults.

Comment: My older parents got into the habit of closing the laptop lid instead of turning it off...which turned out to be sufficient.

Comment: Perhaps something like this? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1056/gnome-shutdown-button/

Comment: How about a desktop shortcut? That's what I did for my elderly relative. They also almost never shut it down.

Comment: I had found but was worried gnome-shutdown-button wouldn't work because the post was 3-4 years old, but it works in 22.04.3 LTS. Now I have to figure out how to do shortcuts for Facebook & Yahoo mail.